# MLB 2K12 PAL Xbox360 Not Available?

Tags: xbox-360, pal

It appears MLB2K12 was not produced this year to work outside of the United States?

I cannot find any reference to a PAL version for use here in Australia and also Europe. Last year 2K11 was available.

This seems ridiculous especially considering NBA, NHL and NFL are all available in PAL as well. Why would they stop a whole audience region?

Can anyone please prove me wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a quick GameFAQs search for the [relevant game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/650816-major-league-baseball-2k12/data) shows that it does not have any data available for EU.

Looking at the release data for the [previous game](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/612199-major-league-baseball-2k11/data) shows a release gap of about three months between US and EU.  It may be that it's just not released yet.

Comment: Interesting, the AU date didn't come long after but the EU and JP did. Either way I see there could still be hope, even if it could stupidly be not towards the end of the season. Heck, I'd even settle for a digital download release. Thanks for the links, you can have the bounty!